# Apply a git patch to a series of renamed files

Tags: git

I have created a patch which modifies a series of files, as well as adds some new ones.

I am attempting to apply this patch on a older release branch, but it fails due to the modified files not existing in tree.

(Extract of some of the errors)

```
error: polyglot/java.hh: does not exist in index
error: polyglot/v7.hh: does not exist in index
```

This is because the modified files were renamed from .h to .hh in a commit not present on the older  release branch.

How do I apply this patch, given that I am modifying files ending in .hh but the tree contains those files with .h endings?

Comment: Did you produce this patch from a commit (or several) in the same repo that you are trying to apply it on?

Comment: Yes ___________ (15 char minimum)

Comment: @Fred Do you get an error? Can you put it in the  question?

Comment: If it is coming from the same repo, try cherry-picking the revisions involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying it on top of a *newer* commit where it can be applied (not necessarily newer, it can be older, whatever allows you to apply the patch) and then cherry-pick the resulting commit on top of the revision you really want. So... something like

```
git checkout -b temp <one-commit--or-branch-that-allows-the-patch-to-be-applied>
git apply some-patch
git add .
git commit -m "Here's a patch I need to be applied"
git checkout <where-i-really-want-it-applied>
git cherry-pick temp
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

the hacky but imho quickest way : edit the file names in your patch file

```
# change this line :
diff --git a/polyglot/java.hh b/polyglot/java.hh
# to :
diff --git a/polyglot/java.h b/polyglot/java.h
```

Comment: There are significantly more files than the ones I posted, more than I would prefer to edit manually.

Comment: It looks like you simply needed `git cherry-pick`, so your problem is solved. For the record : replacing `.hh` with `.h` on lines that begin with `diff --git` can be done with sed : `sed -e '/^diff --git/s/\.hh/.h/g'`